# Safari links in unordered list are broken

Tags: html, css, list, hyperlink, safari

http://www.ifma.org/professional-development/career-center

If you visit this link with Safari (I think OS X only), the links don't work in the middle section. These type of styled links:

View featured job openings »
Receive personal job alerts »
Search for jobs by keyword, location and industry »
Access career coaching resources »

When you use any kind of bold property or html tags it makes the link not functional. You can't click it and it just seems as though it's text.

In the following source code, if you take away the `<strong>` tag it works. You can't use `<b>` tags or font-weight properties either.

```
<p>Whether you are a seasoned facility manager or just getting started in the profession, IFMA offers the resources you need to find the perfect FM position and advance your career.</p>
<p> </p>
<ul>
    <li><strong><a href="#">View featured job openings &raquo;</a></strong></li>
    <li><strong><a href="#">Receive personal job alerts &raquo;</a></strong></li>
    <li><strong><a href="#">Search for jobs by keyword, location and industry &raquo;</a></strong></li>
    <li><strong><a href="#">Access career coaching resources &raquo;</a></strong></li>
</ul>
<p style="text-align: right;"><strong><a href="#" sfref="[pages]55de3a18-5745-481b-9394-8706690e491e">View FM career guide &raquo;</a></strong></p>
<div class="button"><a href="#"><strong>Create your JOBNet account &raquo;</strong></a>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a javascript error on that page, which might have something to do with the problem. And, the links doesn't work in Firefox either, until I put `display: block;` on them.

Comment: Did you put the display: block; property within the a tag?

Comment: Yes, just to test to see what was up. The point is, when looking at the rendered code in Firebug, the `<li>` "lights up" (ie, shows like a block of content), but neither the `<strong>` nor the `<a>` does, which leads me to believe you might have either some weird CSS, or some javascript bugging it, hence why I mentioned the javascript bug as well.